# Add ngAnimate Dependency on module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I already linked the script to my html file for the angularjs,sanitize and animate:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
```

and when i added the ngAnimate as a dependency to my module just like this:

```
var nameSpace = angular.module("OscarApp", ["ngSanitize","ngAnimate"]);
```

all my variables inside my expression were displayed as it is not on what was initialized on the variable, just like this:

```
{{item.award_title}}
```

what seems to be the problem? I just want to follow this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bcv46xKJH98).

Comment: Did you check the browser console for errors ?

Comment: there were no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me...
This prints 2 to the screen

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="OscarApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  {{1+1}}
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var nameSpace = angular.module('OscarApp', ['ngSanitize','ngAnimate']);
```

Angular version 1.3.0-rc.3 (latest download from angularjs.org)

Comment: you're right the version of my angularjs is not compatible with my angular-animate.thanks by the way.

Answer (score 1):

This snippet shows that there is no problem with the unit. 
maybe you have a problem elsewhere.

```js
var nameSpace = angular.module('OscarApp', ['ngSanitize','ngAnimate']);

nameSpace.controller('OscarCtrl',['$scope',function($scope) {
    $scope.item={ 'award_title' : 'The Lord of The Rings' };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="OscarApp" ng-controller="OscarCtrl">
{{item.award_title}}
</div>
```